# Should I bother myself with roslisp?

Tags: ros, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I am choosing whether or not to dive into roslisp. It seems that tutorials are quite obsolete right now. The quesion is for experienced users:

How good is lisp-ROS integration nowdays and where is it going? Will it be maintained in the future?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206900/should-i-bother-myself-with-roslisp?/) by [mukhachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/21666/mukhachev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code for roslisp is maintained and there are some people actively using it.
But it is true that the tutorials are not properly taken care of... I'll look into it at some point in May.

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [firstprayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22028/firstprayer/) on 2015-04-21**:
I've been trying to work out a simple ros hello world for a day but still gets nothing... can you provide some simple tutorial code that could work under catkin system? My email is zhangty10@gmail.com, thanks in advance!

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2015-04-21**:
You can find the code for the tutorials here: https://github.com/code-iai/roslisp_tutorials/
The only thing you need to do to get them to run with the current roslisp version is to comment out all the `add_lisp_executable` lines in the two `CMakeLists.txt` files.

**Comment by [firstprayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22028/firstprayer/) on 2015-04-21**:
Right now in order to run the script with ros, I'm putting extra header to the lisp file as mentioned in http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp/Tutorials/OrganizingFiles, and put
install(PROGRAMS
src/beckon.lisp
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
in the CMakeList.txt. But it can't work...

**Comment by [firstprayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22028/firstprayer/) on 2015-04-21**:
...saying ROSLISP does not designate any package

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2015-04-21**:
Yes, you're definitely doing something wrong, at least the install line seems suspicious. Please create a new question with proper examples of your CMakeLists and the executable script.

**Comment by [firstprayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22028/firstprayer/) on 2015-04-21**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/207561/create-executable-roslisp-script/ I'd be very appreciated if you could have a look at it :)